# Converting PHP date range to MYSQL individual dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, calendar, range

I have an availability calendar in which I am currently adding in dates one by one, and using a mysql query to determine if there exists a row with a certain date and changing the class of the day to "booked" (Red).

I would like to enter in a range into my form, and process it through php (or mysql) into multiple, individual dates. My date format is M/D/YYYY, or MM/DD/YYYY, both are accepted. Unfortunately, when I built my calendar, I did not use the date format in sql for entries, but used varchar.

Is there a way to enter into my form for example 1/1/2014-1/3/2014 and have php convert that to 1/1/2014, 1/2/2014, 1/3/2014, and then have a mysql INSERT query to insert multiple values at once?

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
$adcp_data = array(
'date'      => $_POST['date'],
'customer'  => $_POST['customer'],
'notes'     => $_POST['notes'],
            );
insert_adcp($adcp_data);
header('Location: adcp.php?success');
exit();
```

the insert_adcp function looks like this:

```
function insert_adcp ($adcp_data) {
    array_walk($adcp_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($adcp_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $adcp_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `adcp` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
```

}

My workaround and last resort will be to add multiple text inputs and just add multiple dates manually so I only have to submit once. But a range is so much faster!

As a last note, if I could have those multiple entries keep the "customer" and "notes" values for each date in the range that would be amazing. I am prepared to lose those fields though to make this work. Thanks

Comment: Sure, PHP's a programming language. It'll do whatever you want it to. Doing a date range is trivial. As for your DB, stop working on code and fix the date fields **NOW**. Convert them to a REAL native date/datetime type. Leaving it as varchar will just cause you massive suffering in the long run.

Comment: Yup, ok I'll do it you've convinced me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
$day = new DateTime($_POST['range_start']);
$end = new DateTime($_POST['range_end']);

$all_dates = array();

while ($day <= $end){
  $all_dates[] = $day;
  $day->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

That will give you an array of DateTime objects each of which represents a day in your range.  You can get each object back into a string by calling DateTime::format() and passing 'm/d/Y' as the format string.

As for getting multiple entries into MySQL, the INSERT syntax allows `INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (row1), (row2), ... (rowN)`

(this is clearly not not tested or the final code you would use -- just written into this web form from memory ... you'll have to write it out properly with input sanitation and range checking and whatnot.)

Comment: ...looks good! The correct php-way would be: `$day->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))` 
[You can test it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42fc3d5019f15cd02fbd461be530a92cb92929ad)

Comment: This is great thanks Brad. Its very close, what it is producing is the final date a number of times equaling the number of days in the range. Troubleshooting, if I echo $day in the while loop, it seems to be working fine. Something is happening while I am appending the dates to the array

Comment: Ok I've solved it like you said it required some tinkering but you put me on the right track... thanks! I just kind of suck mysql queries I always have syntax errors. The problem was that I could not insert a datetime object into the table as a string. So I just created a new variable called $sqlday and used that for my injection and used $day as the variable to use in the while loop. Perfect! Maybe not the best way but its what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value from the input match your range format, capture the parts and generate the **from** and **to** dates.

```
if (preg_match('%\A(?<fromMonth>\d{1,2})/(?<fromDay>\d{1,2})/(?<fromYear>\d{4})-(?<toMonth>\d{1,2})/(?<toDay>\d{1,2})/(?<toYear>\d{4})\Z%', $str, $res)) {
    $dates['from'] = mktime(0, 0, 0, $res['fromMonth'], $res['fromDay'], $res['fromYear']);
    $dates['to']   = mktime(0, 0, 0, $res['toMonth'], $res['toDay'], $res['toYear']);
}
```

Generate the range between from and to dates.

```
for ($date = $dates['from']; $date <= $dates['to']; $date = strtotime('+1 day', $date) ){
    $dates['range'][] = date('m-d-Y', $date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, **strtotime** is more usable for your case. You can found definition at php.net site:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php